# Set position/rotation/scale of vertex group to an empty

Tags: geometry-nodes, vertex-groups

I'm trying to link a vertex group to an empty. I want copy the empty's position, rotation and scale to the vertex group of an object. So far I have it working but its limited to a vertex group that share the same Z coordinates.

[image]

How can I have this effect with a vertex group that don't share a plane? I like that rotation element of the setup above finds the center of the vertex group - is there a way of using this center to then set the position and scale of the vertex group according to the empty?

Comment: Do you want to implement hook modifier in GN?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This setup should work:

[image]

How it works step by step:

1. Reset position of vertices by subtracting their median position. So that points are in center of coordinates and you can easily do the next steps:
2. Scale vertices by multiplying by empty's scale.
3. Rotate vertices like you did, but around center of coordinates (0,0,0)
4. Move vertices by difference between empty and median position of points.
5. Now undo the first step to get points back, with transforms applied

[image]

Comment: Works perfectly! Thank you!